# Back and front panel usb port not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Back and front panel usb port not working on Ubuntu 12.04. Please help me and suggest me the solution of this issue.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Is it disabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

If it is on ubuntu side then check these two files

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Remove **blacklist usb_storage** if it is there and save the file.

```
/etc/rc.local
```

remove **modprobe -r usb_storage** if it is there and save the file.

Now reboot your system and your USB port will work unless any hardware problem exists.